# A function that's supposed to call by reference not working

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

I need to return the value by Call by Reference,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int Splitting(int *,int);
int main()
{
    int x = 1234567891,x1=x,a1,b1,count=0;
    a1=Splitting(&x,count);
    b1=x;
    printf("a1=%d,b1=%d",a1,b1);
}


int Splitting(int *x,int count)
{
    int x1=*x,x2, a = 0, b = 0, a1 = 0, b1 = 0;

    /**Some code logic used**/
    a1=12345,b1=67891;
    x1 =(int *) a1;
    return b1;
}
```

I need to return the value `a1`, `b1`.

Where b1 through return statement and `a1` through call by reference. So I need to set the value `x1=a1;` Its not working.

Please suggest.

Comment: Use *x = a1 instead of x1=a1

Comment: "*need to set the value `x1=a1;`*" Why?

Answer (score 5):

You are assigning `x1` when you should assign `x` in your code

instead of

```
x1 =(int *) a1;
```

write

```
*x = a1;
```